# Redshift taking too long for first execution of queries when i change the parameters

Tags: amazon-redshift

We have a table with a large dataset. There are two performance issues we are running into:

1. As per `aws` documentation the first time we execute, it takes longer but all subsequent executions (even with filter values changes) should be quicker. That's not consistent when we run test queries from query editor on `aws` console.
2. And when we ran the same queries from lambda functions (nodejs) it's taking even longer, most of the time twice as long and causing the gateway timeout errors.

Comment: We need more information to help you. Please provide the size and type of your cluster, the DDL of the table being queried (you can replace the column names), the number of rows in the table, and the query being run.

Comment: Regarding item1, this refers to query compilation. If you run 2 similar queries and they take similar time then the issue is not related to compilation. Much more likely that your query or table structure needs to be optimized.